# Shipping quote depending on order total

Tags: ubercart

I am a long time drupal user and a first time ubercart user. I apologize if this question has been asked in the past. I could not find the answer through google, ubercart.org or the forums here.

We are planning on shipping our product USPS flat rate. I would like the shipping cost to depend on the order total. Is this possible?

Something like this:

0-$99.99 - $5.99

$100 - $350 - $9.99

$350 - $500 - $11.99

$500+ - Free

I am running drupal 7 with ubercart 7.x-3.4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate the following Übercart modules:

1. Shipping
2. Shipping Quotes
3. Flat rate

Go to http://yoursite.com/?q=admin/store/settings/quotes and click on "Add flat rate quote". Fill out the from and submit it. The next form should be the conditions form. Create the necessary condition(s), for example, 0 < order:order-total AND order:order-total < 100 as a data comparison. To enter the total values (i.e. float numbers) click on the "Switch to data selection" button near the bottom. Repeat this for all of your total ranges.